# Does a service in vb.net honors datacontract of a Model of C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, wcf, serialization

I have a service written vb.net and a method which return a single project object for a given id. I want the serializer to honor the datacontract and datamember defined in the Project class which is written in C#.

1. Is is possible?
2. If yes, where am I doing wrong.

The Project class(in C#)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract(name="Project")]
Public Class MyProject{
    [DataMember(name="manager_name")]
    public string ManagerName{ get; set; }
}
```

The Projects Service

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Class ProjectService
    <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>        
    Public Function ShowProject(ByVal projectId As String) As Project
        Dim p As New Project
        p.ManagerName = "Furious Manager"
        Return p
    End Function
End Class
```

Now I get this as response

```
{
  ManagerName: "Furious Manager"
}
```

while I want it to be

```
{
  manager_name: "Furious Manager"
}
```

Right Now I have got it working using another vb.net Class `VProject` which maps all the fields from C# class `Project` and puting `DataMember` and `DataContract` in that.

Comment: You can do this easily if the project class is in a separate assembly, like a class library.   Then you just need for your VB project to reference the C# assembly.  There might be a way to mix C# and VB.NET in the same project, but I'd recommend against it.

Comment: @Tim The C# `Project` model is in a separate dll which is referenced by vb.net but it does not seem to work.